# Autocomplete list does not show all possible completions with BindingSource.Item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete

I've got a BindingSource for a DataSet. I'm fairly new to this whole binding business and databases, and it took me hours to figure out how to use BindingSource to get to an item, because the Row method was not included in the autocomplete. Not to confuse anyone, here's some sample code:

```
Dim somePreperty As String

Dim dataSet As New MyDataSet
Dim table As New MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter
Dim source As New BindingSource

source.DataSource = dataSet
source.DataMember = "SomeMember"
table.Fill(dataSet.SomeMember)

lablCabinet.DataBindings.Add("Text", source(0), "MemberID") '<This works fine>'

someProperty = source.Item(0).Row("ProductModel") '<So does this>'
```

The code runs perfectly and does exactly what I want. My problem is the following: When I've typed in `source.Item(0).`, autocomplete does *not* display `Row` in the list. Is this perhaps not the best way to do what I'm doing? Is there a reason it's hidden? Is this a good coding practice to do so? The fact that is wasn't there took me lots of time Googling, so I'm trying to figure out whether it's a Visual Studio glitch or my own.

Thanks in advance! = )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source.item(0) returns an object, so intellisense has no idea what is is.
You know what it should be, the compiler does not.
If you cast it first to a table or assing it to a table, intellisense will kick in.

So either:

```
ctype(source.item(0),datatable)
```

Or

```
dim tbl as datatable=source.item(0).
```

Comment: Ahh.. Can't believe I missed that! Thanks! = )))